# VBA Access transferspreadsheet - do warnings, but no data

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code:

```
StrSheetName = "Weekly Account Balances"
StrTableName = "Account Weekly Balances"
fReportingFile = fDirectory & "\" & fReportingFile

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, StrTableName, _
    fReportingFile, True, StrSheetName & "!"
```

I have verified that the sheet name, table names are correct and fReportingFile are correct using a break at the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.  I have also verified that 123 records are in the "Weekly Account Balances" sheet.

However, no records are transferred and I don't receive a warning.

I have also checked to see if there are any error tables created in the Access DB, but there are none.

Obviously, I have something wrong with the transfer call, but because I'm not getting any messages, I don't know what it is.

Why might I not be receiving any messages and no data is transferred?

Comment: Does it work if you make "Weekly Account Balances" the first sheet, and omit the `Range` parameter? Is `Weekly Account Balances!` even valid syntax for this parameter?

Comment: Thanks.  I intent to import to Access from Excel.  I have not tried moving the sheet to the first sheet.  While that may work, it would affect the whole layout of my workbook, causing consternation to the user.  Why would I not receive a warning/error message?

Comment: I just tested this and it appended even with the target as the second sheet. Last argument syntax is valid.

Comment: I verified warnings were thrown for overflows, data type mismatches, and nulls in required fields. Was using Access and Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Obviously, I have something wrong with the transfer call

No, that is correct, and it works - if, of course, your path and file names is pointing to an existing file, and you have specified the correct worksheet name.

So, *double-check* every parameter and your workbook.

Comment: Thanks. I did find an error in the Table Name.  But I still wonder why I didn't receive a warning like "invalid table" "no table found" or something.  Oh well, at least it works.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: OK. Thanks for the feedback. Then please mark as answered.